why does linux resend packet and change headers RAW sockets unix
I have this code down below I use to send raw socket on unix with sendto function. it works fine. If the packet is 802.11 frame, as I send the packet it gets resent by the OS with some modifications.
My 802.11 Radiotap header is normally 26 bytes, and there is a 4 byte FCS (Frame Check Sequence) at the end of the packet.
The resent packet's header reduces down to 13, and FCS gets deleted. so 17 bytes missing in every frame. Not just missing, but the header is completely modified.
Here is an example from wireshark. I send 802.11 frames, ack packet(40 bytes) and authentication packet (60 bytes) and they get modified and resent by the Os.(I tried on ubuntu and kali linux. Same behavior). You will see 40 60 are the ones I sent and the rest packets are 17 bytes removed like explained.

Here is more info about the packets, this is the flags of the header from the original packet I send.. (as said 26 bytes)

This is the header of the modified and the one sent by the OS.

Notice some flags like Channel dbm Antenna signal etc are removed and data retries TX are flagged.
I use a custom network adapter that supports monitor mode to send the raw packet. I know since I hardcopy-paste auth packets from another program to send with my adapter, the MACTIMESTAMP could be wrong, or dbm and channel might be modified. (even though channel/dbm info doesn't exist on an 802.11 frame)
Why does linux and ubuntu do this ? because the ack frame was hard-copy from the built-in adapter, I know signal dbm/channel might be modified but why does OS resend ?
I also tried this on ubuntu 20.04 and kali linux. They both behave the same. So this is an underlying behavior of linux to resend raw 802.11 frames that are sent with sendto().
This is the ack packet that I create in C,
unsigned char acknowledgePacketToIphone7PlusFromTPLINK[] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x1a, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x42, 0xb7, 0x63, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x10, 0x02, 0x99, 0x09, 0xa0, 0x00, 0xd2, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, //until here 26 bytes radiotap header
        0xd4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x82, 0xd6, 0xb0, 0x18, 0x38, 0x7f,  // 802.11 frame data
        0x6b, 0x14, 0xdf, 0x38 // fcs at the end 
};

and this is the code I have, which has nothing to do with this. Also, this resending behavior doesn't happen when I, for example, switch each byte to 0x01(so disable 802.11 formation)
#include <net/ethernet.h> 

//initialize data
struct sockaddr_ll ll; // => link layer
struct ifreq ifreq_i;

int sock_raw = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)); // => socket is layer 2


//Network Interface Name
memset(&ifreq_i,0,sizeof(ifreq_i)); memset(&ll,0,sizeof(ll));
strncpy(ifreq_i.ifr_name,"wlan1",IFNAMSIZ-1); 
 
if((ioctl(sock_raw,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifreq_i))<0) printf("index failed");
 
printf("indeks=%d\n",ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex);

ll.sll_ifindex = ifreq_i.ifr_ifindex; ll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL); ll.sll_family = PF_PACKET;

//binding socket to the interface
if(bind(sock_raw, (struct sockaddr *)&ll, sizeof(ll)) == -1){ printf("Err: bind failed %d\n", errno); }

unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65526); //memset(&buffer, '\0', 65511);


int sendlen = sendto(sock_raw, &auth, sizeof(auth), 0, 0, 0);

How can I stop this on linux, or learn exactly why this happens? Much thank you.
UPDATE:
I also tried sendto without Radiotap header and keep the FCS, of the array above.
unsigned char ackToIphone7PlusFromTPLINKWithoutRadioTap[] = {
        0xd4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x82, 0xd6, 0xb0, 0x18, 0x38, 0x7f
};

on the wireshark capture of sending computer, I get this log: (Error no radiotap header) 
Update:
interesting, I tried some things now. Tried to remove the first 26 bytes from the array, the Packet becomes malformed and not emitted by any thirdparty listener adapter.
(I assume my sending adapter sends, but I can't see it on captured on wireshark due to it being malformed) Yet on my sending adapter's interface on wireshark... I can see the packet as malformed.

data retries and TX is present on the OS's send trial... Why is this happening ? I found no useful resource. Try to copy and send my ack package to see on monitor mode.


Here is more info about the packets, this is the flags of the header from the original packet I send.. (as said 26 bytes)

You're confusing "radiotap" headers with 802.11 headers. There's no such thing as "802.11 Radiotap".
"Radiotap" is not a real header; it is not part of the 802.11 packet that was sent or received. It's a capture-only pseudo-header that describes what "environment" information – aside from the actual packet – was recorded as part of the capture process, but actual 802.11 frames have none of this information and it does not make any sense to attempt to send it via sockets.
Since the Radiotap pseudo-header describes the capture environment rather than the captured data, it's completely normal that a locally-sent frame will have different parameters than one received through a physical antenna. That, on its own, doesn't change the packet data that got sent.

I updated some edits. If I listen to the packets from another adapter(not the sending one) I don't see any double sends. I assume the adapter drops that packet because it seem to be malformed. But on my sending adapter.. still there... How to avoid that then ? Thank you so far!

I tried killing NetworkManager I will also try to kill wpa_supplicant to see if it changes anything
